# How to make a non-linear potmeter more linear

Tags: potentiometer, linear, non-linear

I have an "Expression pedal" that worked fine on my old keyboard (Gem WX2+) but works almost like a digital switch on my new keyboard (Roland VR-09).

The recommended expression pedal is a Roland EV-5 which has the schema at the bottom right of this page:

[image: Service notes for Roland EV-5]

I measured the pins of my old pedal and the schema is probably like this (have not opened it yet):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feG6XE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An important difference is that the Roland pot is Lineair, while mine seems to be logarithmic. When close to the heel position I can easily navigate close to a wanted resistance. That becomes increasingly difficult moving closer to the toe (fully pressed) position.

I think it should be possible to tweak it to a more linear like curve by making an adapter, adding a resistor between the tip and the ring to pull the curve up somewhat. And while doing so I can just as well add the minimum volume feature as well. This is what I have in mind so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcQCf8.png)</sup>

I'm not an expert at electronics, so I would really appreciate a peer review of this idea before I order the parts. I'm not sure if the value of the curve correction pot is ideal? At the maximum setting, the total resistance would be 9.6K which is a little lower than the 10K of the Roland pedal...

In fact I'm not sure if this idea would work at all, but since a new pedal is quite expensive and has a smaller "throw/range/angle" than my old one, I'd really like to keep my trusty old pedal with a hack if possible. Any other suggestions are welcome off course!

Comment: The circuit diagram says 'special taper', not linear. Can you measure it to find out the actual taper?

Comment: easiest way is to remove the log taper pot and install a linear taper pot

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thanks, I didn't notice that. I can't measure the taper of the EV-5 since I do not own one. But you gave me an idea, I can log the midi response curve of my current pedal by doing a few sweeps with a constant speed. I guess the inverse of that curve is what I should try to go for in order to get it more lineair...